# How to get specific JSON data from REST API using Nodejs?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb

I want to get JSON data of a particular lets say match=2 data from all matches.
I am not able to get required data which is stored in MongoDB.

JSON response:

```
{
    "_id": "5a63051735aaddd30d1d89cc",
    "id": 1,
    "season": 2008,
    "city": "Bangalore",
    "team1": "Kolkata Knight Riders",
    "team2": "Royal Challengers Bangalore",
    "toss_winner": "Royal Challengers Bangalore",
    "toss_decision": "field",
    "result": "normal",
    "dl_applied": 0,
    "winner": "Kolkata Knight Riders",
    "win_by_runs": 140,
    "win_by_wickets": 0,
    "player_of_match": "BB McCullum",
    "venue": "M Chinnaswamy Stadium",
    "umpire1": "Asad Rauf",
    "umpire2": "RE Koertzen",
    "umpire3": ""
  }
```

I am able to get all JSON data of 577 total matches using below code.

```
app.get('/api/matches', (req, res) =>{

    matches.find({}).then(eachOne => {

        res.json(eachOne);

    });

});
```

But now I do not want to get JSON data of all matches instead I want to get JSON data of match having `id:2` how can I get that I tried using below code but it gets JSON data of all matches.

```
app.get('/api/matches/:match_id', (req, res) =>{

    let match = req.params.id;

    matches.find({match}).then(eachOne =>{

        res.json(match);
    });

});
```

In matches.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

let Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const matchSchema = new Schema({

    match_id:{
        type:Number,
        required:true
    },

    season:{
        type:Number,
        required:true
    },

    city:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },

    date:{
        type:Number
    },

    team1:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },

    team2:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },


    toss_winner:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },

    toss_decision:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },

    dl_applied:{
        type:Number
    },

    winner:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },

    win_by_runs:{
        type:Number,
        required:true
    },

    win_by_wickets:{
        type:Number,
        required:true
    },

    player_of_match:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },

    venue:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },

    umpire1:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },

    umpire2:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },

    umpire3:{
        type:String
    }

});

const matches = mongoose.model('matches', matchSchema);

module.exports = matches;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost right. You just need to specify the right query:

```
app.get('/api/matches/:match_id', (req, res) =>{
    let match = req.params.match_id;
    matches.findOne({id: parseInt(match)}).then(m =>{
        res.json(m);
    });
});
```

Also consider that `match_id` from url is a string, so you need to check it and convert to number (I used `parseInt`)

Comment: Why `parseInt(match)` it is already I number see matches.js ?

Comment: Your code works even if I use `match_id: match` instead of `match_id: ParseInt(match)`

Comment: Ah! Yes! I forgot that you are using mongoose...it convert it in number for you.

Comment: I am new to mongodb so does mongoose convert string into number by default.

Comment: Mongoose does it

Comment: When I made changes to my code as mentioned in your answer. Whenever I go to `http://localhost:5000/api/matches/6` or `http://localhost:5000/api/matches/3` it gives same JSON response and not diffferent why so ?

Comment: For different URL's it should give different JSON response but I am not able to get different JSON response ?

Comment: Sorry, my fault. You should let `req.params.match_id` not `req.params.id`

Comment: Does match `2` exists?

Comment: I have replaced `id` with `match_id`  see my matches.js (matches model) file and JSON response you will see the difference.

Comment: see https://imgur.com/a/98dCK it shows JSON data of response `http://localhost:5000/api/matches` and on `http://localhost:5000/api/matches/2` it should give JSON data of particular match.

Comment: Why in the response there's no `match_id` field? Are you sure that your data is correct standing the schema in `matches.js`

Comment: Is it mandatory to have same field name in schema as that of JSON response because I have replaced `id` with `match_id` in schema

Comment: The you need to change the query to match the field: `matches.findOne({id: match})`

Comment: Can you edit the code in your answer please so that I can try it out

Comment: Done it! Try and let me know.

Comment: This means that the match with id = 2 does not exists in the database. Try to query directly the db.

Comment: Don't know. Try to parse the id using `parseInt`, everything seems correct I can't help you. The "strange" thing is that in the model you are not declaring the `id` but the `match_id`, try to change the model according to this.

Comment: on using `parseInt(match)` it works like a charm now. Please edit your answer :)

Comment: Can you help me out here please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48366646/how-to-get-multiple-json-objects-using-nodejs-and-mongoose

Answer (score 0):

You must be using bodyparser by default .

You are doing wrong.

```
app.get('/api/matches/:match_id', (req, res) =>{



    // instead of req.params.id write req.params.match_id
   let match = req.params.match_id;

    // when you write {match} there is nothing {id : match}

    matches.find({match_id : match}).then(eachOne =>{

        res.json(eachOne);
    });

});
```

Comment: My matches.js i.e matches schema is like this https://imgur.com/a/PFeas

Comment: The field in JSON response is `id` but in matches.js Schema I have named it as `match_id` in mongodb is it allowed to name them different or do I need to use same name for fields.

Comment: add full image or file , it is half image. or add the match.js in question.

Comment: check it out I have added matches.js

Comment: In JSON response I have just added only 1 JSON object but it gives around 577 objects

Comment: What is means you rename `id` to `match_id` ? If you have `match_id` in mongodb do same for mongoose and when you are inserting from any outside json api use `match_id` because mongodb have same name . What you means you have named `match_id` in mongodb , change your json id to match_id

Comment: For `POST` and `Update` `Delete` operation should I use `match_id` or `id`

Comment: when I go to `http://localhost:5000/api/matches/3` nothing is displayed by making changes as you said in your answer.

Comment: On api you can use what ever you want id , xyz, etc . But for matching in query you have to use `match_id`

Comment: Ok got it but can you edit your answer as it does not work

Comment: It is displaying all JSON data and not of a particular match why ?

Comment: Check that , and also tell what `match_id` having . do `console.log(match_id)`

Comment: What I could not get ?