# How to get multiple JSON objects using nodejs and mongoose?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb

I want to get all the JSON objects having `season:2008` or `season:2009`. For season field there are 2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016 values.

I want to get all JSON objects having field `season:2008` through an API endpoint. See below code for more clarification but it only returns `null`.

JSON response :

```
{
  "_id": "5a63051735aaddd30d1d89cc",
  "id": 1,
  "season": 2008,
  "city": "Bangalore",
  "team1": "Kolkata Knight Riders",
  "team2": "Royal Challengers Bangalore",
  "toss_winner": "Royal Challengers Bangalore",
  "toss_decision": "field",
  "result": "normal",
  "dl_applied": 0,
  "winner": "Kolkata Knight Riders",
  "win_by_runs": 140,
  "win_by_wickets": 0,
  "player_of_match": "BB McCullum",
  "venue": "M Chinnaswamy Stadium",
  "umpire1": "Asad Rauf",
  "umpire2": "RE Koertzen",
  "umpire3": ""
}
```

Code:

```
/*      <---Uncomment
app.get('/api/matches/:match_id', (req, res) =>{

    let match = req.params.match_id;

    matches.findOne({id: parseInt(match)}).then(Match =>{

        res.json(Match);
    });

});
*/     <---Uncomment

app.get('/api/matches/:season', (req, res) =>{

    let Season = req.params.season;

    matches.find({season: parseInt(Season)}).then(eachOne =>{

        res.json(eachOne);
    });

});
```

In matches.js :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

let Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const matchSchema = new Schema({

    match_id:{
        type:Number,
        required:true
    },

    season:{
        type:Number,
        required:true
    },

    city:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },

    date:{
        type:Number
    },

    team1:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },

    team2:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },


    toss_winner:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },

    toss_decision:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },

    dl_applied:{
        type:Number
    },

    winner:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },

    win_by_runs:{
        type:Number,
        required:true
    },

    win_by_wickets:{
        type:Number,
        required:true
    },

    player_of_match:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },

    venue:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },

    umpire1:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },

    umpire2:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },

    umpire3:{
        type:String
    }

});

const matches = mongoose.model('matches', matchSchema);

module.exports = matches;
```

Whenever I go to URL `http://localhost:5000/api/matches/2008` or `http://localhost:5000/api/matches/2010` it gives `null`.

Comment: Looks like your response is empty. What do you get when you query the db directly on such aquery?

Comment: @Zlatko No that query works on db check https://imgur.com/a/xkFzf

Comment: @Zlatko check out the question I have edited it

Comment: can you set `mongoose.set('debug', true);` in js and see the query fired?

Comment: @Saravana In app.js or matches.js

Comment: @stone in app.js

Comment: put your main server file also... and routes file also if any

Comment: @AshishChoudhary Check the code

Comment: @AshishChoudhary `app.get('/api/matches/:season'....` works when `app.get('/api/matches/:match_id...` is commented but If I uncomment `app.get('/api/matches/:match_id...` then only `app.get('/api/matches/:match_id...` works and not the other

Comment: @AshishChoudhary I am not able to use `app.get('/api/matches/:match_id...` and `app.get('/api/matches/:season...` simultaneously why so ?

Comment: Now your both the routes are identical...you have to make different routes for both queries...  because queries does not know what is `match_id` and `session`... change it to `app.get('/api/match_id/:match_id`... if you keep same name for the routes then query which is before in the code will be executed first

Comment: I have sent a message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now your both the routes are identical...you have to make different routes for both queries... because queries does not know what is match_id and session...  if you keep same name for the routes then query which is before in the code will be executed first

change your both the routes

```
    app.get('/api/match_id/:match_id)

    app.get(/api/matches/:season)
```

Answer (score 0):

Before http://localhost:5000/api/matches/2010 before the /api/matches/:season there should be a route name. Lets say your route name is match.js you the url would look like http://localhost:5000/match/api/matches/2010. Depends how you defined the index.js

Comment: I have created matches.js when I go to `http://localhost:5000/api/matches` it shows this JSON objects (total 577 JSON objects) https://imgur.com/a/ae60C

Comment: I just want to get thos JSON objects how have `season:2008` fields when I navigate to this URL `http://localhost:5000/api/matches/2008` it gives `null`

Comment: What changes do I need to make in `app.get()`

Comment: Example in app.Get: `var match = require('./routes/matches.js');
app.use('/matches', match);`
Try something like this. This must be in index.js

Comment: I think I my `app.get()` is wrong any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: `http://localhost:5000/api/matches/` works but `http://localhost:5000/api/matches/2008` does not work.